# Need Server side validation for Search Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net textbox which does not allows special characters except %. i want to validate this on server side. I have written the code. But the regex for that is not working. I have written that code in Javascript. But the Issue is that it is not validating server side. please see the code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#ctl00_topNavigation_txtSearch').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            window.location.href = "search.aspx?tx=" + $(this).val();
            return false;
        } else {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[.a-zA-Z0-9\b _ _%]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
    $('#ctl00_topNavigation_txtSearch').bind("cut copy paste", function (e) {    
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Also please see the html of search textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="txtfld-search"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please help, so that I can validate it server side.

Comment: If you want to execute some code server side using an asp.net framework, then your code can't be in JavaScript. I add the [asp.net] tag which is much more relevant.

Comment: "I have written that code in Javascript. But the Issue is that it is not validating server side."  
 Since when do you use js to validate on serverside? Use a `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Answer (score 2):

**Server Side Validation:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="txtfld-search"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtSearch" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="req"
            ValidationExpression="^[.a-zA-Z0-9\b _ _%]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**Update**

**Validating *Server Validator Control* using *Javascript*:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#txtSearch').bind('keypress', function(event) {
   if (Page_ClientValidate("req")) //req is the ValidationGroup name
   {
         //alert("valid");
   }
   else {
           //alert("Invalid");
   }
   });
});
```

This code works i have tested it!

**Note:** "req" is the ValidationGroup name of a RegularExpression validator!
Hope this helps you!

Comment: the ID is not validating the regex.

Comment: "ID is not Validating regex"? do u want to validate the textbox on click of button? or on key press u want to run server side validation? plz mention clearly! just dont say.."server validation" "Not Working" etc!

Comment: Actually after putting your RegularExpressionValidator, the code seems not to be working. please see the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Cdja/1/

Comment: your fiddle doesnt show any thing on screen(Textbox) not rendered :(

Comment: now check: http://jsfiddle.net/4Cdja/3/ i have changed the textbox type from asp to input